# Troubleshooting a slow database server with no load

Tags: mysql, router, fedora

I'm getting ready to soft launch my website and I've run into some problems with what I think is being caused by my MySQL database running on Fedora.

All websites run fine, just as I'd expect, but any pages that establish a database connection hang until the connection is established, and then bang, the site loads as it should.

Ex. My landing page (http://www.thrusong.com) doesn't make a database connection and loads quickly. User profile pages (http://www.thrusong.com/john) make a database connection and load slowly, even though most of the data comes from memcached and the database currently has no load on it.

This problem just came up yesterday when my router died and I began using my Pace 2Wire modem with built-in router. Before, my old router was set to handle everything. My ISP says the settings in the modem are correct.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: skip-name-resolve solved your problem? Can you suggest an edit tothe answer and accept it please?

Answer (score 0):

Your web server and your MySQL databases are running on the same machine? If yes, use the Unix socket connection (usually /tmp/mysql.sock) instead of using port 3306. By doing it, you will eliminate any network issues you might be having.

If that doesn't solve your problem, at least you will be sure that is nothing related to network connectivity between MySQL and your website.

Comment: They're on separate boxes. The MySQL server is just MySQL and XMPP, there's a storage server (CentOS) and the webserver is a third machine (CentOS).

Comment: So you definitely have a connectivity issue going on. Try pinging the MySQL server from the webserver to check the latency. Your modem router may be having trouble resolving names or routes between the two servers, you better not trust your ISP and check the modem yourself.

Comment: These are the results from the ping:

    PING 192.168.1.150 (192.168.1.150) 56(84) bytes of data.
    64 bytes from 192.168.1.150: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.269 ms
    64 bytes from 192.168.1.150: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.141 ms

Basically, the same thing over and over. Ranges from .140 to .310 ms.

Comment: Hmm, my code indenting formatting won't work. Also, I should note that "Connection information" on the database says 100 mb/s while the other two servers say 1000 mb/s.

Comment: Hmm.. ping times are pretty good. Have you checked if your MySQL server is able to resolve network addresses? May be it was relying on your old router for resolving network names and is having troubles now. Sorry for the guessing method but giving your scenary of recent router changing, I really think your problem is on the network not on the deamons.

Comment: No worries, I'm so happy to receive help from you. I have a feeling it's something weird in the network settings too. How do I check if it can resolve addresses?

Comment: Hmm, I set skip-name-resolve and it seems to be better, so I'm on the right track. Thanks!

Comment: Great, good to know! Try setting the webserver name and ip on /etc/hosts.